# Suppress Smaller values in SPSS Frequencies output

Tags: spss

Is there an SPSS syntax that can help me suppress smaller values when displaying frequencies? I'm able to hide small values using cross-tabs, but when I use Frequencies command I'm not able to suppress or hide small values.

This is my current syntax: Is there another command to add in suppressing output less than 10? Thank you!

```
Frequencies variables = alcoholany 
   /Order=ANALYSIS.
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't get this through the `frequencies` command alone - you'll need to identify those cases first and filter them out before running it:

```
aggregate /out=* mode=add/break=alcoholany/Ncat=n.
compute filt=Ncat>=10.
filter by filt.
Frequencies variables = alcoholany /Order=ANALYSIS.
filter off.
```